# Erl() function not working in 64 bit O365 Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, 64-bit, erl

I work with Excel spreadsheets that use the vba Erl() function for error handling.  The vba code might look something like this:

```
   Sub doSomething()
      Dim v as variant
      Dim v1 as Variant

      On Error goto err_Handler

10    v = "Test"

20    v1 = 1/0        ' Generate error

30    Call doMoreStuff()

      Exit Sub

err_Handler:

      if Erl = 20 then 
          Resume Next     ' Ignore this error

      Else
          Msgbox "Looks Like there is a REAL error somewhere.  Desc = " & Err.Description
      End If

End Sub
```

I am not making a judgement about using Erl in this way.  Personally, I never do, but we have many spreadsheets that have this.

However, in O365 testing on 64 bit Excel it seems like this functionality does not work at all.  In the above code, the program does not read the line number correctly and so the line Erl = 20 returns False when it should be True and hence the program calls the Msgbox when it should ignore the error.

Has anyone else noticed this?  There are apparently dozens of spreadsheets that have this potential issue.  Creating a script that would somehow change the code to something else would be a huge undertaking.

Has anyone else had to deal with this problem and can you outline how you addressed this problem?

Thanks very much

Comment: `the line Erl = 20 returns False` - then what does Erl return?

Comment: It is not consistent.  Most of the time it returns 10 (the previous line number)  but sometimes it returns 0 (as if the 20 is not there at all).

Comment: I suspect that, since Line numbers in VBA have essentially been deprecated, and since Line Numbers are limited to Integer resolution (32,767) and VBA code can have 65,535 lines, that the function was never implemented for 64-bit Office, hence unreliable results.

Comment: You're may be right, but it seems very bad to allow code to be valid and then upgrade and _poof_ it doesn't work anymore.  Surprise!  I suspect this was just missed and will probably be fixed at some point, but that doesn't help us much now.

Comment: I don't know if it will be fixed. `ERL` is not documented at all for the current version of VBA. You may be better served by eliminating it in the code, especially if you're going to be using 64-bit Office.

Comment: for your example, Erl is working as it should for me.
my build is "Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.13001.20254) 64-bit"

Comment: Interesting.  Maybe he problem is with spreadsheets that start out as Excel 2013 and then are moved to O365.  I've tried forcing a recompile, but that doesn't seem to do it.    I wonder if creating a macro to copy the code into new modules in a second workbook stripped of the code might work.  Thanks all for your insights.

Comment: It doesn't work in my Win64/Excel32 VBA 7.1.1087 system too.  Erl is always 0.

Answer (score 0):

> Has anyone else noticed this?

Yes, I can confirm that this issue also exists in the 64 bit version of MS Access, when compiling the database to `accde` or `mde` format. Here are my repro instructions (tested with Version 2112, 16.0.14729.20260 C2R).

1. Create a new empty database with a single module.
2. Fill the module with the following code:

   ```
   Sub Test()
       Dim a As Long
       Dim error_lines As String

       On Error GoTo error_handler

   10: a = 1 / 0
   20: a = 1 / 0
   30: a = 1 / 0
   40: a = 1 / 0
   50: a = 1 / 0

       Debug.Print error_lines
       Exit Sub

   error_handler:
       error_lines = error_lines & Erl() & ","
       Resume Next

   End Sub
   ```
3. Execute the code and notice that it prints `10,20,30,40,50,` in the immediate window. So far, so good.
4. Create a compiled `accde` file with File/Save As...
5. Open the accde file, hit Ctrl-G to enter the VBA immediate window and execute `Test`.
6. Note that the output is now `10,20,0,0,0,`

> Has anyone else had to deal with this problem and can you outline how you addressed this problem?

The obvious workaround is to use your own error line variable, i.e., replace

```
10: FrobnicateFoo()
20: ...

error_handler:
    If Erl() = 10 ...
```

with

```
    Dim line_nr As Long

    line_nr = 10
    FrobnicateFoo()
    line_nr = 20
    ...

error_handler:
    If line_nr = 10 ...
```

However, this would be a good opportunity to replace those meaningless line numbers with well-named variables, e.g.

```
    Dim frobnicating_foo As Boolean

    frobnicating_foo = True
    FrobnicateFoo()
    frobnicating_foo = False
    ...

error_handler:
    If frobnicating_foo Then ...
```